# Invalid hostname in URL HP Performance center

Tags: c, performance-testing

I am new to HP Performance center and recording a script. Recording is done successfully but when I try to run the recorded script

```
Error   797 Action.c(797): Error -32998: Invalid host name in URL="http:\\/"https://www.youtube.com/embed/3IqJIzJPrbw///""   [MsgId: MERR-32998]    Action.c    C:\Workspace_HP\CreateQuoteAndConfigure_KW_CERT_Updated CreateQuoteAndConfigure_KW_CERT_Updated
```

And i don't see anywhere mention of youtube link in the call

this is the call which is failing with the above error:

```
web_custom_request("ClientUI.ashx_3",
    "URL=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/configurator/handlers/ClientUI.ashx",
    "Method=GET",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default",
    "Snapshot=t30.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    EXTRARES,
    "URL=/experlogix/site/styles/MSCRM60-Borders_PACCAR/catHdrTreeMinus.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/resources/styles/custom-2.css?20190926050952", ENDITEM,
    "URL=../images/tbAdd04.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default", ENDITEM,
    "URL=../images/tbInfo01.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default", ENDITEM,
    "URL=/experlogix/site/images/30c67911-796a-425d-89cd-6f622a79d355_printer-32x32.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default", ENDITEM,
    "URL=/experlogix/site/resources/images/icon_caution_25px1.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default", ENDITEM,
    "URL=/experlogix/site/resources/images/icon_pass_25px1.png", "Referer=http://{host_kwsalestoolportal-cert_na_paccar_com}/experlogix/site/pages/ConfigureItem.ashx?target=config&oType=1084&oTypeName=quote&orgName=SalesToolYARCert&id={QuoteId}&PortalUserId=fb1b42fb-a315-e811-816a-005056a20489&PortalWebsiteId={GlobalId}&uiLang=1033&mode=default", ENDITEM,
    LAST);
```

can some one help me how to debug and investigate to fix this error? Very new to HP and C so very naive in this.

Comment: That URL is completely mangled, it is `http:\/https://www.youtube.com...`. That code shown doesn't seem to relate to it.

Comment: Yes, that's what i am also thinking. I checked manually the network calls using F12 developer tool and didn't see any calls to youtube. is there a way in HP performance center settings where I can ignore the youtube calls?

Comment: or maybe instead of using http, i have to force HP to use https rather than http when it comes to youtube calls. can i do that in the code or in any settings?

Comment: No idea. You'd have to check the source or documentation.

Comment: is there a way to capture youtube link and redirect it to https?

Comment: I was able to add youtube call in network traffic filtering in recording options and was able to bypass youtube call.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add youtube call in Network > Mapping and Filtering > traffic filtering in recording options and was able to bypass you-tube call.

Comment: Can you post more details about the solution you found? Other users will certainly find this question if they have the same issue.